# Python 'String Index Out of Range Error'?

Tags: python, string, indexing, range

I am 15 and currently doing a GCSE in Computing. My knowledge is very basic and I've had a bit of trouble with a piece of code I have to write for a 'Vowel Worth Calculator' which is supposed to check through a word and give it a vowel score depending on how many and which vowels it has. I keep getting an error, and I am completely stumped, any help would be appreciated. Here is my source code :

## Vowel Worth Counter

```
print('Welcome to the Vowel Worth Counter!')

word = input('Please input your word, in lower-case, or type Q to quit.')

if word == 'Q' :
    quit()

def vowelcount(word) :
    lettercount = int(len(word))
    vowelscore = 0
    checkcount = 1
    position = 0
    while lettercount != checkcount :
        if word[position] == str('a') :
            vowelscore = vowelscore + 5
        if word[position] == str('e') :
            vowelscore = vowelscore + 4
        if word[position] == str('i') :
            vowelscore = vowelscore + 5
        if word[position] == str('o') :
            vowelscore = vowelscore + 5
        if word[position] == str('u') :
            vowelscore = vowelscore + 5
        position = position + 1
    if lettercount == checkcount :
        print('I have finished calculatiing your Vowel Score.')
        print('Your Vowel score is ' + str(vowelscore) + '!')
        for x in range (0,1) :
            break
vowelcount(word)
```

---

As I said, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You never change `checkcount`, so your `while` loop can never end.

Comment: `while lettercount != checkcount`. You never alter either in your while loop, while you still increment `position`. This is why you're code is dying

Comment: Also, in Python it is far more usual to loop directly over data structures like lists or strings than it is to use an index. `for letter in word:` would be the Pythonic idiom, at least if I weren't going to use more advanced constructions.

Answer (score 3):

The exit contidion in the loop should be:

```
while position < lettercount:
```

Or even simpler, you can iterate over each character in a string like this:

```
for c in word:
    if c == 'a':
        # and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be more pythonic to use the [dictionary data structure](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
vowels = { 'a' : 5, 'e' : 4, 'i' : 5, 'o' : 5, 'u' : 5}

vowelscore = 0

for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        vowelscore += vowels[letter]
```

Comment: Haha! I had written the exact same code, but had resisted from answering the question, because I thought it was a little too cocky. Plus, it did not answer the question the OP asked, "Why his code is not working?". Anyway! :)

Comment: Yeah. I figured since @ÓscarLópez had already answered the OP, I figured I would suggest looking at a data structure he/shre might not have encountered before :). That's funny though

Comment: OK, since we're getting into alternate constructions - define the dict as above, then `vowelscore = sum(vowels.get(letter, 0) for letter in word)`

Comment: Thank you all so much, was not expecting a response!